# Posgtres CASE condition with SUM aggregation evaluates not needed ELSE part

Tags: sql, postgresql

According to [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html):

> A CASE expression does not evaluate any subexpressions that are not
>   needed to determine the result. For example, this is a possible way of
>   avoiding a division-by-zero failure:
>
> SELECT ... WHERE CASE WHEN x <> 0 THEN y/x > 1.5 ELSE false END;

Why does the following expression return an `ERROR: division by zero?` - apparently evaluating the else part:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(0) = 0 THEN 42 ELSE 43 / 0 END
```

while

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(0) = 0 THEN 42 ELSE 43 END
```

returns 42.

EDIT: So the example above fails because Postgres calculates immutable values (43/0) already in planning phase. Our actual query looks more like this:

```
case when sum( column1 ) = 0
            then 0
            else round( sum(   price 
                             * hours 
                             / column1 ), 2 )
```

Although this query doesn't look immutable (depends on actual values), there is still a division by zero error. Of course sum(column1) is actually 0 in our case.

Comment: Your quote is *immediately* followed by "Note: As described in Section 35.6, functions and operators marked IMMUTABLE can be evaluated when the query is planned rather than when it is executed. This means that constant parts of a subexpression that is not evaluated during query execution might still be evaluated during query planning." So what exactly is the problem? The type of check where it makes sense works as described, only checks that make no sense (a constant `43 / 0` value?) throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, I havn't read the note before. I now understand why the simplified example in my question fails. Let me add an example closer to our real code - I am not sure if the Note in documentation explains this as well..

Comment: Actually, PostgreSQL jumps through a bunch of hoops to make that work normally. For example, `SELECT CASE WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 1/0 END` succeeds. You've found a case where PostgreSQL's normal attempt to delay zero-divide evaluation doesn't work, by the looks, probably to do with the aggregate function. I'm not sure it's strictly a bug (it'll depend on SQL standard details) but please report it to pgsql-bugs http://www.postgresql.org/support/submitbug/ . Post a link to this post, but ALSO a fully detailed explanation like you provided above.

Comment: I submitted this as a bug report and will update this question as soon as we know more.

Comment: Here is the link to the mailing list archive: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/BUG-11661-CASE-ELSE-is-evaluated-although-condition-is-true-td5822861.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting example. This does have a good explanation. Say you have data like this:

```
db=# table test;
 column1 | price | hours 
---------+-------+-------
       1 |     2 |     3
       3 |     2 |     1
```

PostgreSQL executes your SELECT in two passes, first it would calculate all the aggregate functions (like `sum()`) present:

```
db=# select sum(column1) as sum1, sum(price * hours / column1) as sum2 from test;
 sum1 | sum2 
------+------
    4 |    6
```

And then it would plug those results in your final expression and calculate the actual result:

```
db=# with temp as (
db(#     select sum(column1) as sum1, sum(price * hours / column1) as sum2 from test
db(# ) select case when sum1 = 0 then 0 else round(sum2, 2) end from temp;
 round 
-------
  6.00
```

Now clearly if there's an error in the first aggregate pass, it never reaches the CASE statement.

So this isn't really a problem in documentation about the CASE statement -- it applies to all conditional constructs -- but about the way aggregates are processed in a SELECT statement. This kind of problem cannot occur in any other context because aggregates are only allowed in SELECT.

But the documentation does need updating in this case too. The right documentation in this instance is "[the general processing of SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#AEN80008)". Step #4 there talks about GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, but it actually evaluates any aggregate functions in this step as well, regardless of GROUP BY/HAVING. And your CASE statement is evaluated in step #5.

### Solution

The common solution, if you want to ignore aggregate inputs that would otherwise cause a division by zero, use the [nullif() construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to turn them into NULLs:

```
round( sum(   price 
            * hours 
            / nullif(column1, 0) ), 2 )
```

PostgreSQL 9.4 will introduce a new FILTER clause for aggregates, which can also be used for this purpose:

```
round( sum(   price 
            * hours 
            / column1
          ) filter (where column1!=0), 2 )
```

Comment: Well, re-reading my answer after you drew more attention to this question, I realise that I didn't even get my workaround right. My approach was workable, but you actually worked out your approach into something that works.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation and even better solution.